# Input voltage drop to 190v after switching over load

Tags: electrical, grounding, neutral

We have an Online-UPS connected as per the diagram. The output is given to a change-over switch.

So If we want to feed the computers direct AC we switch it to Source O (Top) for bypass and if we want to give it UPS-Output we switch to Source 1 (bottom on change-over).

If the Change-Over is set to Top (Bypass) the reading at the UPS Input Terminals are as follows

1. Across Point A and Point B : 230v
2. Across A and Ground : 230v
3. Across B and Ground : 0v

Now if the change-over is set to bottom (UPS Output), the voltages are as follows, Note the UPS output is still not switched on.

1. Across Point A and Point B : 190v
2. Across A and Ground : 230v
3. Across B and Ground : 40v

If I turn the UPS output ON, the UPS starts beeping saying Battery Voltage Very Low please turn off UPS.

Is the connection done wrongly?

Edit: Verified ground between terminals and building ground. All seems to be fine. The UPS is getting Ground from the building's ground.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect your UPS is not grounded correctly. How is ground provided to your load (computers)? What is the change-over switch make and model?

Comment: verified ground connections. Computers are grounded with a wire that is connected to the building's ground terminal. Terminals are showing continuity between ground terminals (Wall Sockets/UPS Ground/Appliance Ground).

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad neutral connection between the UPS and supply. This is also likely stopping it charging, hence the low battery voltage.

Comment: Neutral is bad indeed. Thanks Someone Somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous Setup [image]

So what was happening here is once the change-over was not set to AC, the common neutral was not linking to the UPS output.

Had the wiring reconfigured in the following way. Things are back to normal.
[image]